# Laravel Policies keeps allowing users

Tags: php, laravel, policy

I have created a user policy under `App\Policies\UserPolicy` for the `UserController` to only allow users with id 2 to access . However right now even the users with id 1 is able to access without throwing any error.

```
/**
 * Determine whether the user can create models.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\Auth\User  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
public function create(User $user)
{
    return $user->id === 2 ? Response::allow()
    : Response::deny('You do not own this users.');;
}
```

**Route** :

```
Route::get('user/createProfile' , [UserController::class, 'showCreateProfileForm'])->name('user.profile.createProfile');
```

**Controller** :
`UserController.php`

```
public function showCreateProfileForm()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $this->authorize('create' , $user);
    return view('backend.auth.user.profile.create');
}
```

**Provider** : `AuthServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use App\Models\Auth\User;
use App\Policies\UserPolicy;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */ 
    protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

    }
}
```

When I return `$this->authorize('create' , $user);` from the `UserController@showCreateProfileForm` ,  it keeps returning

```
{
  "allowed": true,
  "message": null,
  "code": null
}
```

Comment: please try : $this->authorize('create' ); and make sure you have: 
 $this->authorizeResource(User::class, 'user'); in your controller constructor

Comment: No it isnt working, the policy is not even being registered.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that there was this method in AuthServiceProvider@boot

```
Gate::before(function ($user, $ability) {
    if ($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Hence, all my authorization kept failing.

The solution would be changing it to

```
Gate::after(function ($user, $ability) {
    if ($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Thank you